# Ignoring one and *only* one update for Big Sur

Tags: software-update, big-sur

I'm running Big Sur (MacOS 11.7.10) on an ancient, 9-year-old MacBook Pro.

I recently received an update notice for Microsoft Office 16.77.1, but I'm not being allowed to apply that update, because it requires MacOS 12, which I don't think is available for a Mac that's as old as mine.

It turns out that the "softwareupdate" utility no longer supports the "--ignore" flag, and therefore, it seems like I can't tell my OS to ignore any further Microsoft Office updates.

I want to continue to accept all other updates in the normal manner (at least all others that will work under MacOS 11).

Is there any way that I can tell my OS to ignore that one update?

Yes, I know I could buy a newer Mac that will accept an upgrade to MacOS 12. But that is a totally unacceptable course of action for me.

Another unacceptable course of action for me is to do nothing and constantly see the update notice for Microsoft Outlook.

Is there anything I can do (even including hacking one or more pieces of MacOS software) that can get rid of that ongoing upgrade notice for Microsoft Office?

Thank you in advance for any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Did you buy Office from the Mac App Store?

Comment: What version of Office is this (365 or one-time purchase or Mac App Store)? Where does the update show? Mac App Store? Microsoft Auto-update? MacOS System updates? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off Microsoft's AutoUpdate independently of your Mac settings.

`/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/Microsoft AutoUpdate.app`

Run that & switch off. I'm in a similar position, my Mac is now too old for office updates…

[image]

Any updates coming from the App Store should 'know' when to stop being offered.

Comment: Thank you! ... but sadly, there is no "Microsoft" subdirectory under `/Library/Application Support` on my Mac, and there's no file on the entire Mac which contains "AutoUpdate.app" as part of its file name.  I guess I'm out of luck.

Comment: What are you searching with? Spotlight is terrible at finding 'hidden & system files. Try [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) - just in case. It *may* be in ~/Library

Comment: I am doing a "find" based from the root directory, running as root. And it's not in ~/Library, either.

Comment: That doesn't find it for me either;)

Comment: EasyFind.app doesn't find it on my Mac, either.

Comment: Ugh! Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Wish you luck, hope someone comes up with a method for your version, which is very slightly newer than mine. [16.5]

Comment: Thank you! And actually, I don't even use Microsoft Outlook, so I guess I could just delete that app.

Comment: And PS: maybe this shows a good reason for you not to update to 11.7! :)

Comment: I tried running the `AutoUpdate.app`, but this thing refuses to be disabled. I guess you meant that if the `Automatically keep MS apps up to date` option was **un-checked**, that this would disable the thing? On my systems (Ventura 13.6 & Mojave) the app still starts itself and nags at me to update my Office apps. I guess I should look for something in `QuickLaunch` that I can disable/unload??

Comment: You could always just bin the MAU app if it exists… Mine seems to be fine once I've checked that box. Hasn't nagged me in ages. I don't really know the differences between versions, though. Mine came direct from MS, not from the App Store & was the last standalone, not tied to 365.